# How to add row in DefaultTableModel under spcific index?

Tags: java, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm building a java application with swing component.
Now I want to create a JTable with 4 fixed row.
In detail I want a JTable(DefaultTableModel) with the last 4 row as fixed with my default value, and throught a Button I want to insert a new row upper this 4 row. There is a metohd to insert a row in a specific point?

Comment: Check out the [DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). There you'll find the `insertRow` method which is what you need. Question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: ok, yuour comment done